# Redundancy in function imports

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, redundancy

I think there is some redundancy in my import but I cant really figure out another way to do it

main.rs

```
mod lib; 
use lib::calc::med_calc;


fn main() {
    let mut numbers = vec![1,21,22,4,2];
    med_calc(& mut numbers)
}
```

to me it seems weird to declare the lib.rs as a module and only then I can use the structs/functions within. Since I've already declared them as modules and public in lib.rs itself.

lib.rs

```
pub mod calc {
    pub fn med_calc(vector: & mut Vec<u8>){
        vector.sort();
        println!("{}", vector[vector.len()/2])
    }
}
```

file tree (used in cargo):

```
src -
    |- main.rs
    |- lib.rs
```

Comment: USE THIS IN MAIN.RS use crate calc::med_calc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have both a `lib.rs` and `main.rs` file in your project, the `lib.rs` file creates a library crate that can be accessed via the crate name in your crate's binary source files (like `main.rs` and `bin/*.rs`).

For example, if the crate is named `rust_tmp`, then you can do:

`main.rs`:

```rust
use rust_tmp::calc::med_calc;

fn main() {
    let mut numbers = vec![1, 21, 22, 4, 2];
    med_calc(&mut numbers)
}
```

No need for a `mod lib;`. Actually, a `mod lib;` is counterproductive to how `lib.rs` is meant to be used.